# Working With Dynamic Multidimensional key-value pairs in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, multidimensional-array, key-pair

Having a thorny problem and only see similar but also simpler solutions on SO.

Is is possible to generate a dynamic key AND dynamic values using JS/JSON?

For instance, let's say I have JSON like this:

```
{
    "email": "user@someco.com",
    "firstname": "Bob",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "company": "ACME",
    "custom": {
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "svc1",
                "desc": "abcdefg",
                "selected": "true",
                "status": "None"
            },
            {
                "name": "svc2",
                "desc": "abcdefg",
                "selected": "true",
                "status": "None"
            },
            {
                "name": "svc3",
                "desc": "abcdefg",
                "selected": "false",
                "status": "None"
            },
            {
                "name": "svc4",
                "desc": "abcdefg",
                "selected": "false",
                "status": "None"
            }
        ],
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "Products",
                "desc": "abcdef",
                "type": "multi",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "name": "Product1",
                        "desc": "abcdef"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Product2",
                        "desc": "abcdef"
                    }
                ],
                "services": [
                    "svc1",
                    "svc2",
                    "svc3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Wines",
                "desc": "abcdef",
                "type": "multi",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "name": "Wine 1",
                        "desc": "abcdef"
                    }
                ],
                "services": [
                    "svc4"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Fruits",
                "desc": "abcdef",
                "type": "multi",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "name": "Fruit 1",
                        "desc": "abcdef"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Fruit 2",
                        "desc": "abcdef"
                    }
                ],
                "services": [
                    "svc4"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

I need to go into the fields and for each field (products, wines, fruits) see if a given service is contained within so that I can go back and generate a product or wine or fruit for each service that requires it.  But I don't want to repeat the services names more than once. The resulting JSON should look something like this:

```
{"svc1":["Products"], "svc2":["Products"], "svc3":["Products"], "svc4":["Fruits", "Wines"]}
```

The hope would be that to generate a dynamic list in Angular I can just turn and loop back through this JSON, pulling out the values for each product, fruit, wine, whatever.

I've been trying a lot of nested for loops and the like but whenever I get more than one layer down the dynamism seems to stop.  I'm guessing that for this to work I need to move between JS Objects and JSON?

Right now I'm trying something like this, which isn't quite working, stringify or no.  And maybe I'm flip-flopping too much between JSON and JS Objects:

```
var outObj = [];    

var fieldItems;
        $.each(jsonObj.custom.fields, function(key, item) {
            fieldItems = item;
            fieldItems.name = item.name;
            $.each(fieldItems.services, function(key, item) {
                var serviceName = item;
//check to see if the serviceName already exists
                if (outObj.indexOf(serviceName) > -1) {
                outObj.serviceName.push(fieldItems.name);
            } else {
                outObj.push(serviceName);
            }

            });
        });

        JSON.stringify(outObj);
        console.log("outObj " + outObj);
```

I get "can't read property 'push' of undefined" errors and the like.  Seems this should be possible from a single nested loop, but maybe I need to just do two passes?  Any other suggestions?

Comment: `if (outObj.indexOf(serviceName) > -1) ` should give you an error, objects don't have an indexOf method. Since it isn't, my guess is it isn't an object, and we need to see how it's defined to recreate your problem.

Comment: Oops...forgot that bit of code, good call.

Comment: Oh... well, then how is `outObj.indexOf(serviceName)` not failing.

Comment: Been staring at this so long I've stopped seeing...edited again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it sounds like overcomplicated solution. You can use basic array methods of javascript to filter out required structure. I am not sure what `profiling_value` in the presented snippet, so I started from the object structure in OP

```
var desiredResult = jsonObj.custom.services.reduce(function(result, service){
  result[service.name] = jsonObj.custom.fields.filter(function(field){
       return field.services.indexOf(service.name) >= 0;
   }).map(function(field){ return field.name; });
  return result;
}, {});
```

This gives the expected result for mentioned object.

`reduce` is required to iterate over all services and accumulate result in one object. Then for each service fields are iterated to `filter` out only those that contain link to this service. And finally list of filtered fields is transformed (`map`) into list of strings - their names - and inserted into accumulator

Comment: Why do i have such a hard time wrapping my head around what `reduce` does, regardless of how many times i read the docs

Comment: Gah...learned JavaScript the hard way and years ago and somehow never seem to have unlearned the old ways of doing things even though that's how I think with jQuery.  Get reduce (keeps me from repeating things), get filter...and then of course map just follows from there.  Kirill, thank you!

Comment: @KevinB, [this MDN description](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) helped me.

Comment: Also wish I could promote this more somehow because this is a great lesson in using reduce, filter, map together when apart they might seem abstract.