# Converting Multidimensional JSON key-value pairs into an Angular Menu (no Angular knowledge required)

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I asked this question here:

[Working With Dynamic Multidimensional key-value pairs in JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975753/working-with-dynamic-multidimensional-key-value-pairs-in-json)

But it's become a bit more involved and I can't get where I'm going from that answer.  If I have a data object that looks like this:

```
{
    "email": "user@someco.com",
    "firstname": "Bob",
    "lastname": "Smith",
    "company": "ACME",
    "custom": {
        "services": [
            {
                "name": "svc1",
                "desc": "abcdefg",
                "selected": "true",
                "status": "None"
            },
            {
                "name": "svc2",
                "desc": "abcdefg",
                "selected": "true",
                "status": "None"
            },
            {
                "name": "svc3",
                "desc": "abcdefg",
                "selected": "false",
                "status": "None"
            },
            {
                "name": "svc4",
                "desc": "abcdefg",
                "selected": "false",
                "status": "None"
            }
        ],
        "fields": [
            {
                "name": "Products",
                "desc": "abcdef",
                "type": "multi",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "name": "Product1",
                        "desc": "abcdef"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Product2",
                        "desc": "abcdef"
                    }
                ],
                "services": [
                    "svc1",
                    "svc2",
                    "svc3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Wines",
                "desc": "abcdef",
                "type": "multi",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "name": "Wine 1",
                        "desc": "abcdef"
                    }
                ],
                "services": [
                    "svc4"
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "Fruits",
                "desc": "abcdef",
                "type": "multi",
                "values": [
                    {
                        "name": "Fruit 1",
                        "desc": "abcdef"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "Fruit 2",
                        "desc": "abcdef"
                    }
                ],
                "services": [
                    "svc4"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

How can I convert that into an Angular menu?  The menu would need to list all of the services, and then if the service has an associated item in "fields" that item should be listed underneath it.  So for instance "svc1" and its description should be listed on a line (got that working) but then "Product1" and "Product2" with their descriptions should appear on the next two lines because you can see that "svc1" is listed in the "services" field for "Products."  Similarly, "svc4" should appear on a line, and then "Wines" and its description on the next line because "svc4" appears in the "services" field of "Wines."

I think the best way is to unpack and re-pack this JSON object in sequential order in the Angular controller and then push this data out to the Angular view but there might be a solution using only the logic available from the view.  I've tried a bunch of nested fors and ifs along these lines (very much not working):

```
var i, j;
var listArray = [];
      for (i = 0; i < $scope.svcs.length; i++) {
          var littleArray = [$scope.svcs[i].status, $scope.svcs[i].name, $scope.svcs.desc];
          listArray.push[littleArray1];
        for (j=0; j < $scope.jFA.length; j++) {
          if ($scope.jFA[j] == $scope.svcs[i].name) {
            if ($scope.jFA[j] == $scope.svcs[i].fields)
            littleArray = [$scope.jFA[j].fields] //...etc
          }
        }
```

...but that logic just keeps getting more and more dense and isn't working no matter now I try to use it.  I liked the simplicity in the answer to the other question but have not had success in replicating it.

So if someone can help me figure out how to get the data into the right sequence using JS I can handle the Angular part.  Or if you're an Angular whiz and have an answer along those lines, even better.

Comment: And no, I can't re-order the existing data...

Comment: mapping the data first is most practical approach. Not really clear what expected results are. Reading this data doesn't make it intuitive. A demo including sample data and html representations of results would help

Comment: Great advice!  Here's a fiddle that shows the expected output. I only put it in a table for presentation purposes so focus on the output and not the HTML. https://jsfiddle.net/rdLznaz7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it was a little hard understanding your question, but I gave it my best shot. Does this fiddle show what you are trying to achieve? <kbd>http://jsfiddle.net/arknr6qz/1/</kbd>

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp',[]);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope)
{

    $scope.checkService = function(service, fieldServices)
    {
        if (fieldServices.indexOf(service) != -1) return true;
        return false;
    };


    $scope.data = {
        "email": "user@someco.com",
        "firstname": "Bob",
        "lastname": "Smith",
        "company": "ACME",
        "custom": {
            "services": [
                {
                    "name": "svc1",
                    "desc": "abcdefg",
                    "selected": "true",
                    "status": "None"
                },
                {
                    "name": "svc2",
                    "desc": "abcdefg",
                    "selected": "true",
                    "status": "None"
                },
                {
                    "name": "svc3",
                    "desc": "abcdefg",
                    "selected": "false",
                    "status": "None"
                },
                {
                    "name": "svc4",
                    "desc": "abcdefg",
                    "selected": "false",
                    "status": "None"
                }
            ],
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "Products",
                    "desc": "abcdef",
                    "type": "multi",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "Product1",
                            "desc": "abcdef"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Product2",
                            "desc": "abcdef"
                        }
                    ],
                    "services": [
                        "svc1",
                        "svc2",
                        "svc3"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Wines",
                    "desc": "abcdef",
                    "type": "multi",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "Wine 1",
                            "desc": "abcdef"
                        }
                    ],
                    "services": [
                        "svc4"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "Fruits",
                    "desc": "abcdef",
                    "type": "multi",
                    "values": [
                        {
                            "name": "Fruit 1",
                            "desc": "abcdef"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Fruit 2",
                            "desc": "abcdef"
                        }
                    ],
                    "services": [
                        "svc4"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestController">
        <div ng-repeat="service in data.custom.services">
            {{ service.name }}
            <div class="indent" ng-repeat="fields in data.custom.fields">
                <span ng-if="checkService(service.name, fields.services)">
                    {{fields.services.values}}
                    <span ng-repeat="value in fields.values">
                        {{value.name}} - {{value.desc}}<br>    
                    </span>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and finally css:

```
.indent {
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: Ronnie, you are close but you are returning the field names when  I actually need what's in the values.  Fiddle of expected output here: https://jsfiddle.net/rdLznaz7/

Comment: So you'll have to `ng-repeat` one more time. How is this? http://jsfiddle.net/arknr6qz/1/ I believe your expected output is wrong on the last service. It should be `wine 1, fruit 1, fruit 2` since service 4 is present in wines and fruits

Comment: Yeah just figured it out myself from your example!  Thanks Ronnie.

Comment: I have to say, I don't know if you looked at the other question, but I really didn't think Angular could even do this.  I knew I could repeat but didn't think it could handle the rest.  So you've opened my eyes to the power of Angular.

Comment: It's a very powerful tool. I'm sure there is a neater way than nested repeats, but you'd have to be able to manip that json data first

Comment: ...which is what the other question started to address.

Comment: well since you said you can't reorder the existing data, I assume you can't change the JSON structure directly. It might not make sense to manip the json first programatically and then run it through angular. When I said manipulat the json, I meant actually change the json structure so you could have something easier to work with

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately that's not an option.